# Show that the curvature of simple arc C is given by $\kappa(q)=\frac{\Vert f'(a)\times f''(a)\Vert}{\Vert f''(a)\Vert^3}$

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis

I need help with this problem:

> Let $C$ be a simple arc smoothly parametrized by $f:D\subset\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$. Show that at the point $\mathbf q\in C$, where $\mathbf q=f(a), a\in D$, the curvature is given by $$\kappa(\mathbf q)=\frac{\Vert f'(a)\times f''(a)\Vert}{\Vert f'(a)\Vert^3}$$ Hint: apply 2.8.20 and 2.8.21.

**2.8.20** $f'(t)=v(t)T_f(t)$

**2.8.21** $f''(t)=v'(t)T_f(t)+(v(t))^2\kappa_f(t)N_f(t)$

I don't know how to begin, I find differential geometry confusing. Can you pleas guide me on how to begin showing this? Thanks.

Comment: You wrote $\mathbf q = f'(a)$; could you have intended to write $\mathbf q = f(a)$ instead?  Cheers!

Comment: Sorry, it is $\mathbf q=f(a)$, not $f'(a)$. Does that modify @GReyes answer?

Comment: I don't think so . . . ;)

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cross-multiply $f'(t)$ and $f''(t)$ using your two formulas. You get $T\times T=0$ and $T\times N=B$ (the unit binormal vector). That is,
$$
f'(t)\times f''(t)=(v(t))^3\kappa(t)B(t)
$$
Taking the norm,
$$
\|f'(t)\times f''(t)\|=(v(t))^3\kappa(t)\|B(t)\|=(v(t))^3\kappa(t).
$$
Now just divide by $v(t)^3$ and use the fact that $v(t)=\|f'(t)\|$ ('speed').

Comment: I don't understand how did you find the cross product of $f'(t)$ adn $f''(t)$. Sorry, I'm used to find the cross product with matrices.

Comment: I am using the properties of the cross product; $a\times(b+c)=a\times b+a\times c$. Also, I am using the fact that the cross product of parallel vectors is zero ($T\times T=0$) and the definition of the unit binormal $B=T\times N$. There is no need for the matrix thing here, just properties and definitions. You use the matrix to cross multiply concrete vectors.

Comment: I see, but I still find difficult to understand how did you went from $f'(t)\times f''(t)$ to $(v(t))^3\kappa(t)B(t)$. Can you please show me how you did the cross product?

Comment: Sure. $f'(t)\times f''(t)=v(t)T(t)\times[v'(t)T(t)+v(t)^2k(t)N(t)]=v(t)v'(t)T(t)\times T(t)+v(t)^3k(t)T(t)\times N(t)$. Since $T(t)\times T(t)=0$ and $T(t)\times N(t)=B(t)$ you get $f'(t)\times f''(t)=v(t)^3k(t)B(t)$ and $\|f'(t)\times f''(t)\|=v(t)^3k(t)\|B(t)\|=v(t)^3k(t)$.

Comment: Thanks. Why $v(t)T(t)\times[v'(t)T(t)+v(t)^2k(t)N(t)]=v(t)v'(t)T(t)\times T(t)+v(t)^3k(t)T(t)\times N(t)$? I mean, why $v(t)$ and $v'(t)$ are multiplied by scalar multiplication and $T(t)$ is multiplied by cross product with itself? Is there a formula for this?

Comment: Scalars can be pulled out of the cross product: $(kv)\times w=kv\times w$ (where $k$ is a scalar, $v$ and $w$ are vectors). Also, $v\times (kw)=kv\times w$. The cross product is a bilinear operation. All the scalars on either factor can be multiplied together and pulled out.

Comment: So $v(t)$, $v'(t)$ and $\kappa(t)$ are scalars?

Comment: Sure. $v(t)=\|f'(t)\|$, $v'(t)$ is a scalar as the derivative of a scalar and the curvature is a scalar (the length of the second derivative using natural parametrization).

Comment: Ok, I get it know. Thanks for your help!